# Mysql: количество строк в другой таблице

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Тестовая структура:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  id INT
);

CREATE TABLE b (
  id INT,
  a_id INT,
  sum INT  
);

INSERT INTO a SET id=1;
INSERT INTO b SET id=1, a_id=1, sum=2;
INSERT INTO b SET id=2, a_id=1, sum=3;
```

Надо в один селект получить для каждой строки из `a` количество записей из `b` с `a_id` равным id текущей строки, и сумму всех полей sum. Если таких записей нет, строка из `a` все равно должна оставаться в выдаче.
Как писать не представляю совсем, кроме того, что с `join`.

Пример выдачи:

```
id -- count(*) -- sum(sum)
1  --  2       --  5
```

Comment: Напишите как вы себе это представляете

Comment: @ArchDemon запрос? Откровенно говоря, сейчас я уже подозреваю что это невозможно. Честно, вообще без понятия как

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе всё ровно так, как вы и написали в условии: считаются `count` и `sum` группируя по `a_id`. А в целом таблица `а` джойнит как раз-таки ту таблицу с группировкой.

```
SELECT a.id, tmp.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.a_id, COUNT(b.a_id) as `count`, SUM(`sum`) as summa
            FROM b
            GROUP BY b.a_id
) tmp
ON tmp.a_id = a.id
```

В итоге если для `a` нет записей в `b` - то там будут `null`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35471b/8

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `a`.`id`, SUM(`b`.`sum`), COUNT(*)
FROM `a`
LEFT JOIN `b` ON `a`.`id`=`b`.`a_id`
GROUP BY `a`.`id`;
```

На фидле получил результат как у вас